# Would like to show link in asp

Tags: asp.net, html

Is there any possible way to edit this code

```
<asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" style="top: 165px; left: 888px; position: absolute;" Font-Names="verdana" ForeColor="black" Font-Size="13px" />
```

so instead of showing the username I can display a img that links to a page

Comment: Did you try `LoginName1.FormatString = "<img src='myimage.jpg' />";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PraVN said, `FormatString` should be greate for this :

```
<asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" FormatString="&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.myurl.com&quot;&gt;&lt;img src='myimage.jpg' /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;" />
```